# Copy paste row as values for conditional formatting

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I made essentially an organizer for workflow moving between 5 sheets based son status. I used various sources and got everything to work fine.
Now when the row copies and pastes to the next worksheet I want to paste as values so that my conditional formatting is unaffected by the pasted rows, because it currently adds the conditions for each row that’s pasted in.

I think I have to make the adjustment to the pastecell but am not sure the correct way

Currently:

```
If sheet2.range(“a2”) = “” then
Set pastecell = sheet2.range (“a2”) 
Else set pastecell = sheet2.range(“a1”) .end(xldown).offset(1,0)
End if 
If status = “In process” then       status. Offset(0,-2).resize(1,14) .copy PasteCell
```

If status = “In process” then status.offset(0,-2).resize(1,14) .clearcontents

Comment: `PasteCell.Resize(,14).Value = status.Offset(0,-2).resize(1,14).Value`

Answer (score -1):

In order to paste as values, you'll have to use `Range.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` method; replace the above code with this:

```vb
Set Pastecell = Sheet2.Range("A2")

If status = "In process" Then
   status.Offset(0, -2).resize(1, 14).copy
   PasteCell.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
   status.offset(0, -2).resize(1, 14).clearcontents
End If
```